# Implementing UINavigationControllerDelegates animationControllerFor method disables edge-swipe-pop feature

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

**Short:**
Implementing `func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?` from `UINavigationControllerDelegate`

causes the edge-swipe-pop feature to not work

**A bit longer:** I am implementing the above mentioned delegate method to determine the presenting viewcontrollers state, this part works great. I am returning nil inside the method as I actually don't need any animationController for fancy effects. But implementing this method causes the edge-swipe-pop feature/gesture to not work. I tried getting the default behaviour with various approaches like implementing animationcontrollers or interactivecontroller, even tried getting the default animation/interactive-controller but that didn't work either. I can apply the gesturerecognizer to the whole view but this is not the expected behaviour.

Did anyone have had similar issues and is there a solution to this issue that i don't know of?

Here is a NavigationController as an example:

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override init(navigationBarClass: AnyClass?, toolbarClass: AnyClass?) {
        super.init(navigationBarClass: navigationBarClass, toolbarClass: toolbarClass)

        delegate = self
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

extension MyNavigationController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        //removing or commenting out this method enables the edge-swipe-back feature/gesture
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am encountering the exact same thing...

Comment: @TomvanZummeren nope

Answer (score -1):

In your `init` methods, you need to set:

`self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self`

That will re-enable this feature.